# No puedo lograr sacar divisores e imprimirlos en JLabel

Tags: java, netbeans

este es el código:

```
 if(e.getSource() == botonCalcular){
            int num = 0, i = 0;
            num = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText());
            
            for(i = 1; i <= (num) ; i++){
                if((num) % i == 0 && i < (num)){
                    jlabel3.setText(String.valueOf(i + " ,"));
                    jlabel4.setText(String.valueOf((-(i)) + " ,"));
                } else if((num) % i == 0 && i == (num)){
                    jlabel5.setText(String.valueOf((i + " ,")));
                    jlabel6.setText(String.valueOf((-(i))));
                }
            }
        }
```

no puedo lograr que se impriman de forma continua ni siquiera usando `jlabel` por separado. Si puedo hacerlo por cmd, pero imposible para crear un programa ejecutable...

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema? ¿Y por qué quieres usar JLabel?

Comment: mi problema es que no logro hacerlo funcionar igual que en cmd, y nose si exista otra forma de poder agregar los divisores en alguna etiqueta...recién estoy comenzando con java y mucho mas inexperto en netbeans. no puedo hacer que se impriman los divisores que recorrer el for y cumplen la condición.

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que todo numero es divisible por si mismo para simplificar el codigo tome todos los numeros del 1 a num y verifique con el metodo divisor si eran divisores y si eran los imprimia es algo parecido a lo que tienes que hacer en tu codigo.

```
  import java.util.Arrays;
    
   
    public class NewClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int x = 6;
            for(int i =1;i<=x;i++){
                if(divisor(x,i)){
                System.out.println(i);
                }
            }    
        
        }
        public static boolean divisor(int  i,int x){
         return i%x == 0;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: gracias no sabia de ese método!!!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar una variable tipo String para almacenar los divisores, y posteriormente establecer el contenido de dicha variable como el texto de un JLabel. Además el código puede ser optimizado:

```
int num = 0;
num = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText());
String divisores = ""; //se crea una variable de tipo String vacía 

for (int i = 1; i<=num; i++){ //la variable i se puede declarar aquí
    if(num % i == 0){ //el resto de condiciones están implicitas en la condicional del for
        //en la variable se acumulan los divisores, uno por uno
        divisores = divisores + (i + ","); // es equivalente a divisores += (i + ",")
    }
}

jlabel3.setText(divisores); //una vez que termina el ciclo, se muestra la cadena en el JLabel
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!